# Django 1.7 makemigration Hang

Tags: django

I am trying to get on Django 1.7, and following the instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south).  Unfortunately, the process seems to be hanging with the output below:

```
[Watt] ~/Projects/proj/proj master > python proj/manage.py  makemigrations
/home/me/.virtualenvs/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/comments/__init__.py:13: RemovedInDjango18Warning: django.contrib.comments is deprecated and will be removed before Django 1.8.
  warnings.warn("django.contrib.comments is deprecated and will be removed before Django 1.8.", RemovedInDjango18Warning)

/home/me/.virtualenvs/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/managers.py:36: RemovedInDjango18Warning: `TreeManager.get_query_set` method should be renamed `get_queryset`.
  class TreeManager(models.Manager):

/home/me/.virtualenvs/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tagging/forms.py:12: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form TagAdminForm needs updating
  class TagAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

/home/me/.virtualenvs/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mptt/admin.py:15: RemovedInDjango18Warning: `MPTTChangeList.get_query_set` method should be renamed `get_queryset`.
  class MPTTChangeList(ChangeList):
```

What should I do to diagnose the hang?  Could this be a function of some of the dependencies being out of date for 1.7?

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer, I narrowed it down to a 3rd party application that was not compliant with Django 1.7.  That app was using some old tech to manipulate the user model, which the 1.7 model loading rework broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161264/544059), you should try running the migrations one by one for the core Django packages, then your own apps and finally for the 3rd party dependencies. I upgraded them to the latest stable versions as well - this might have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing there is hanging. Those are all warnings about deprecated functions that will be removed in Django 1.8. So, you need to investigate your usages, determine what the new guidance is, and make the updates before installing Django 1.8. For the time being, in Django 1.7, you should be okay.