# Django 1.7 makemigrations freezing/hanging

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, django-migrations

I'm finally upgrading from Django 1.6 to 1.7, and removing South in the process.  I followed the [official Django instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south) and removed all my old numbered migrations.  Now I'm trying to run `python manage.py makemigrations` to get the new migrations to continue moving forward with 1.7's migrations module, but it completely hangs and the only output I get is the following:

```
bash -cl "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-Dj17/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py makemigrations /Users/me/Coding/mysite"
/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-Dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/_doctest.py:59: RemovedInDjango18Warning: The django.test._doctest module is deprecated; use the doctest module from the Python standard library instead.
  RemovedInDjango18Warning)

/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-Dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py:27: RemovedInDjango18Warning: The django.test.simple module and DjangoTestSuiteRunner are deprecated; use django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner instead.
  RemovedInDjango18Warning)
```

And then even if I leave it for hours, nothing happens.

What is happening here?  How can I debug a manage.py command?

**Update:**

After running with `dtruss` per **@WilfredHughes**'s advice, I get the following output (output at the top has been clipped because was too long for StackOverflow):

```
sudo dtruss python manage.py makemigrations

open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/collections.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/os\0", 0x7FFF57D95E40, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/os.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/osmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/os.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/os.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/sys\0", 0x7FFF57D95E40, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/sys.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/sysmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/sys.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/sys.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/gettext\0", 0x7FFF57D95E40, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/gettext.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/gettextmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/gettext.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/gettext.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/threading\0", 0x7FFF57D95E40, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/threading.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/threadingmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/threading.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/threading.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/warnings\0", 0x7FFF57D95E40, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/warnings.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/warningsmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/warnings.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/warnings.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/suit/locale\0", 0x7FFF57D96630, 0x1000)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_select2/locale\0", 0x7FFF57D96630, 0x1000)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/locale\0", 0x7FFF57D96630, 0x1000)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/locale\0", 0x7FFF57D96630, 0x1000)        = 0 0
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/locale/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/locale/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000)       = 0 0
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = 5 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95F48, 0x1B6)      = 0 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95328, 0x1B6)      = 0 0
lseek(0x5, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
lseek(0x5, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95218, 0x1)        = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x5, "\336\022\004\225\0", 0x1000)         = 356 0
read_nocancel(0x5, "\0", 0x1000)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/locale\0", 0x7FFF57D96630, 0x1000)        = 0 0
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/locale/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/locale/en.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000)       = 0 0
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = 5 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95F48, 0x1B6)      = 0 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95328, 0x1B6)      = 0 0
lseek(0x5, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
lseek(0x5, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95218, 0x1)        = 0 0
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/locale/en_US.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000)      = -1 Err#2
read_nocancel(0x5, "\336\022\004\225\0", 0x1000)         = 356 0
read_nocancel(0x5, "\0", 0x1000)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/locale\0", 0x7FFF57D96630, 0x1000)        = 0 0
read_nocancel(0x5, "\0", 0x1000)         = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
open_nocancel(".\0", 0x0, 0x1)       = 5 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D947B0, 0x1)        = 0 0
fcntl_nocancel(0x5, 0x32, 0x7F8D8B21F800)        = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
stat64("/Users/me/Coding/mysite\0", 0x7FFF57D94720, 0x7F8D8B21F800)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djrill/views.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djrill\0", 0x1100004, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF2)      = 6 0
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo\0", 0x7FFF57D95CB0, 0x1000)      = -1 Err#2
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95328, 0x1B6)      = 0 0
lseek(0x5, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
lseek(0x5, 0x0, 0x1)         = 0 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95218, 0x1)        = 0 0
stat64("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x7F8D8B21F800)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdbmodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/MySQLdb.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/src/unicodecsv-master/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/.virtualenvs/mysite-dj17/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.24.0.21/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)       = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
stat64("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle\0", 0x7FFF57D95FE0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oraclemodule.so\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle.py\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)      = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/cx_Oracle.pyc\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)         = -1 Err#2
open_nocancel(".\0", 0x0, 0x1)       = 5 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95E20, 0x1)        = 0 0
fcntl_nocancel(0x5, 0x32, 0x7F8D8B84F800)        = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x5)      = 0 0
stat64("/Users/me/Coding/mysite\0", 0x7FFF57D95D90, 0x7F8D8B84F800)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/Users/me/Coding/mysite/mysite.log\0", 0x209, 0x1B6)      = 5 0
lseek(0x5, 0x0, 0x2)         = -1730136042 0
fstat64(0x5, 0x7FFF57D95DE8, 0x2)        = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
```

**Update:**
Per comments and answers below, I tried completely shutting down and restarting Postgres to ensure that there were no open connections, and `makemigrations` still hangs.  However, what I **did** notice is that if I kept Postgres completely shut down (confirmed by trying `$ psql` and getting no response), and then trying `makemigrations`, I had the same behavior.

Comment: If you press Ctrl-C, what does the traceback look like?

Comment: @WilfredHughes if I press ctrl+C, nothing happens.  No traceback.  I have to Cmd+W terminal entirely.

Comment: You're on a Mac by the looks of things. Try running it with [dtruss](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) to see what it's doing.

Comment: @WilfredHughes indeed I am and thanks for the advice; I ran again with `dtruss` and got the output pasted above.  Unfortunately, it doesn't mean much to me except that it potentially is hanging due to something with the database modules, which makes sense.

Comment: What if you run `python manage.py makemigrations` from the command line, not from PyCharm?

Comment: @utapyngo same issue

Comment: Try removing the `migrations` directory and running `python manage.py makemigrations app_name` for each of your Django apps.

Comment: @jdotjdot If you start the command with `--traceback`, it should give you a trace when you press ctrl-C. I think this would be more helpful than `dtruss` since the trace would be at the Python level and also avoids running with root permissions. `python manage.py makemigrations --traceback`

Comment: @user193130 using `--traceback` actually still won't give me the traceback, because when I do Ctrl+C it still hangs--remember, it can't receive SIGTERM :(

Comment: @jdotjdot Oh I see... Guessing it's probably stuck in some native call. I'm using Aptana Studio on OSX and it has an interactive debugger which helped me out a lot; maybe you can give a try? You'll have to set up the run/debug configuration to run your command though which should be fairly easy to figure out. A quick search also revealed [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), though I've never used it before.

Comment: what specific django version are you using? (microversion and all)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try disabling all of your installed_apps and seeing if that solves the problem. If it does, isolate the one causing the issues. Then set debugging traces.

Comment: Turned out it was `djcelery` causing the issue and I just had to upgrade it to solve the problem.  Great idea, I feel silly for not having thought of it myself.  Wish you'd answered before the bounty expired.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried upgrading all the packages to their latest stable version and running migrate for the dependencies one by one. Then it worked.

Comment: This error happens when I follow django first tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/ after making migrations in tutorial they advise you to make some more changes to the model and migrate again, but it hangs if I change anything.

Answer (score 4):

Django 1.7 had this bug apparently that can cause migrations for a large enough number of models to freak out. They said they were doing something about this, and seems like they might have fixed it in 1.7.1.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7.1/

It's the third entry, and there's a few more improvements that may be connected to this.

Heard it first in this talk, hope it solves your problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjIXZ-XX2SM

Comment: Using Django 1.7.2, and that's what's failing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed (following first django tutorial) that adding new field to the model class causes makemigrations to hang. Editing existing field, removing field, adding new model class - it all works, only adding new field to existing class hangs. Im not sure if this is also the case in 1.8 version.

Edit: this only happens in git bash under windows 7. when I try windows cmd console - it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are there open connections to the database you're migrating?  If so, that is probably the reason your migration hangs.  See [this south bug](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/209) for more information.  I realise that Django 1.7 does not use south and that bug refers specifically to south.  Migrations are built directly in Django 1.7, but since [other people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988361/django-1-7-long-migrations-never-ends) have the same problem, I fear this issue is still around.

Comment: No dice. I tried completely shutting down Postgres and restarting and running `makemigrations`, and I still have the exact same issue. However, per update to question, running `makemigrations` with `psql` entirely shut down causes the same error--not sure if that's meaningful or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, and as suggested in another answer i tried to eliminate applications in INSTALLED_APPS and then found my app which was causing this behavior.

Finally this line of code was the cause:

```
import fabric
```

when i removed it everything worked fine.